# java.lang.IllegalStateException: TimerTask is scheduled already: Rationally using of Timer and TimerTask in Android

Tags: android, exception, timer

I write an application that connects to server and sends him *ping* commands, server answer with *pong* commands.

I want to implement connection timeout mechanism. I think it will be following:

- Client send *ping* and start timer with timertask and delay
- When client receive *pong*, timertask is cancelled.

Also, I want to optimize memory. So, not to recreate TimerTask every time I send *ping* command. I try code below:

```
private final Timer mSystemLogoutTimer = new Timer();
private final TimerTask mLogoutTask = new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        mMessageInterface.onConnectionTimeout();
        cancel();
    }
};

private void ping() {
    sendRequest(RequestBuilder.formPing());
    mSystemLogoutTimer.schedule(mLogoutTask, CoreConst.PING_ANSWER_DELAY);
}

private void onPong() {
    mLogoutTask.cancel();
}
```

But I get following error when try to schedule TimerTask second time:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: TimerTask is scheduled already
at java.util.Timer.scheduleImpl(Timer.java:572)
at java.util.Timer.schedule(Timer.java:459)
```

I don't understand, because I call `cancel()` on TimerTask.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.
Thank you for answers!

Comment: What does `mLogoutTask.cancel();` return? Also, have you tried without the 'memory optimization'?

Comment: First time it returns true, second false.

Comment: Without 'memory optimization' all works fine and `cancel` always return true

Comment: Ok, this is enough to determine what is happening I guess (see below).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`TimerTask.cancel()` does not necessarily prevent the execution of the task. According to [the SDK documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html), it returns `true` when the execution was actually prevented, `false` otherwise.

Looks like this it what happens with your code as the first time `true` is returned, but not the second, leading an `IllegalStateException` to be thrown when calling `Timer.schedule()` right after.

You should check `TimerTask.cancel()`'s return code, and recreate your `TimerTask` when `false` is returned: the `TimerTask` is burnt and cannot be reused at that stage.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Try to write memory  optimized code for Android fails :)

Comment: How you think, it is right to start timertask to detect ping timeout?

Comment: Well, regarding the optimization it depends: some memory optimization can be really useful sometimes. But it is a good practice to first have something that works (even as a prototype), and then to try to implement it in a way it would consume as less CPU or memory resources as possible. Provided the gain is relevant. There is no need to spend days on something that would lead to a gain of 2ms each time the user fills a form, for example. Regarding the ping timout design, I have nothing to say as as don't know the context enough.

Comment: Thank you for explanation, I agree with you. Lets close this discussion :) Thank you again!